# Upload an image for a product PHP (Prestashop)

Tags: php, image, upload, hyperlink, prestashop

I want to create a module to up images for products, 
and here is the part when I did not know what to do

```
$product = new Product();
        $image = new Image();
        $langId = (int) (Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
        $name = Tools::getValue('product_name');
        $product->name = array($langId => $name);
        $product->price = Tools::getValue('price');
        $product->wholesale_price = Tools::getValue('wholesale_price');
        $product->active = false;
        $product->is_virtual = true;
        $product->cache_has_attachments = true;
        $product->id_category_default=3;
        $product->reference = $this->context->cookie->id_customer;
        $product->link_rewrite = array($langId => Tools::link_rewrite($name));
        $product->add();

        $image->id_product = intval($product->id);

            $image->position = Image::getHighestPosition($product->id) + 1;
            if(Image::getImagesTotal($product->id)>0)
             $image->cover = false;
            else
              $image->cover = true;
            $languages = Language::getLanguages();
            foreach ($languages as $language)
             $image->legend[$language['id_lang']] = 'Click to view';
            $id_image = $image->id;
            $image->add();
            $tmpName = tempnam(_PS_IMG_DIR_, 'PS');
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['design']['tmp_name'], $tmpName);
```

Above you see my code to add an image for the product but I got nothing in my BackOffice what should I do to make it appear and upload the image with the different sizes

Comment: Why are you trying to display an image in the backend?

Comment: to be seen by the administrator and so he/she accept it (as you see in the code, the product is disabled by default)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy the image in the right directory and resize it on all PrestaShop format. You can do something like this after your last line:

```
$new_path = $image->getPathForCreation();
ImageManager::resize($tmpName, $new_path.'.'.$image->image_format);
$imagesTypes = ImageType::getImagesTypes('products');
foreach ($imagesTypes as $imageType)
    ImageManager::resize($tmpName, $new_path.'-'.stripslashes($imageType['name']).'.'.$image->image_format, $imageType['width'], $imageType['height'], $image->image_format);
```

I hope that will help you.

Comment: I have already found the solution but thanks for your answer It must work !

Comment: @user2507171 well. What's the solution?